# Centering modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to center this date picker to make it easier to use on mobile, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm currently trying this method: https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

```
.picker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}
```

...but no luck. Horizontally it centers, but not properly and the modal scales with the window size. Vertically it doesn't center at all.

I've also tried centering it with jQuery, but I couldn't get that to work properly either.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qos2v29e/

Comment: It works if you remove `position: absolute` from `.picker__holder` -- http://jsfiddle.net/qos2v29e/1/

Comment: Not quite I'm afraid. Check the full screen result: https://jsfiddle.net/qos2v29e/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Sorry, I posted the un-edited version. This is working... http://jsfiddle.net/qos2v29e/2/

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using the flexible box model (flexbox).  Create a flex container the size of your screen, then make your modal a child of the flex container.  Flexbox allows for vertical and horizontal centering.

Great intro to flexbox here:
http://flexboxin5.com/

Comment: Tried using flexbox here, but it's not working for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/6ucsrewx/